# script to create windows 7 new sticky note

Tags: windows-7, clipboard, sticky-notes

I wrote a program that will take text on my clipboard and write it to a temp file and then open that temp file in notepad. The program is called paste.exe and I put it in my path, so I could just WIN+R, type paste and have a the text pasted to a new text file. This is a huge time saver for me personally.

I'd like to create a similar program that will create a new Windows 7 sticky note with what's on my clipboard but I'm having a hard time finding a way to automate the process.

stikynot.exe is Sticky Notes and as best I can tell there are no command line arguments.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You're correct that there are no command line args. Dumping the binary stikynot.exe doesn't revel any strings that looks like a command option or easy way to hack in. It looks like it contains WCF code that provides an interface to a configuration file for notes.
So instead of trying to script that limited UI, why not attempt to talk to this configuration/database, to add your notes there?
The sticky notes file is kept under the AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Sticky Notes directory for each user, in the file StickyNotes.snt.
The file type is unique to StickyNotes. Here is an [overview of the structure.](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Sticky_Notes)
Here's some documentation about [interfacing this type of strutured Storage document](http://www.endurasoft.com/vcd/ststo.htm).

Answer (score 2):

You might look into using [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to automate the process.  You may need to change your thinking a bit, but it should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

If you are able to install freeware than consider Stickies.

You can setup a hotkey in Stickies to paste the clipboard into a new sticky note.

Stickies is one of The best free apps, ever, for the PC.

I have used Stickies for over a decade.

Windows 7 Sticky Notes SUCK compared to Stickies!

http://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/stickies/

Comment: Why is it the best? Why not list its features rather than telling us how great it is

Comment: Good point. Features I liked:  fully skinable, including very clean skins, comes with skin tool,  rtf text,  many features for 'on top' behavior and setting,  hiding/showing stickies,  creating stickies from clipboard,  hiding for a 'snooze' period,  daily reminders,  graphical sticky editing.